# Getting an "Use of uninitialized value in string ne at..." even when checking that the value is defined

Tags: perl, operators

i have the following piece of code that throws an uninitialized warning in perl

WARNING: "Use of uninitialized value in string ne at ......."

```
    foreach my $sub (@{$decoded->{subscriptions}})
    {
        print STDERR Data::Dumper::Dumper $sub;

        if (defined $sub and defined $sub->{status} and $sub->{status} ne 'unsubscribed')
        {
            push @subscriptions, $sub;
        }
        else
        {
            my $nowDate = Lib::Time::getSQLTime();
            $nowDate =~ s/ /T/;
            my $expireDate = $sub->{next_charge_at};

            my $subtract = str2time($expireDate) - str2time($nowDate);

            if ($subtract > 0)
            {
                push @subscriptions, $sub;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm checking that the value i need is defined but even then it's throwing this warning and I'm not exactly sure why it's doing it.

The value of $sub is:

```
{
      'source' => 'xxxxxx',
      'billing_system' => 'xxxxxxx',
      '_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'status' => 'unsubscribed',
      'userid' => xxxxxx,
      'billing_key_type' => 'msisdn',
      'created' => '2013-06-20T23:02:13',
       'next_charge_at' => 2013-06-21T23:02:13',
      'product' => 'xxxxxx',
      'billing_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
};
```

When i changed the 'ne' to 'eq' it doesn't throw that warning even though for both tests i use the same data to compare the value against.

I also tried printing the value of of $sub->{status} before i do the check and it displays either 'unsubscribed' or 'subscribed' so that value is not empty for each time it does the check.

Can someone help me out with this please? Let me know if you require more info.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem. Are you sure you do not have a typo in `status` in the string comparison?

Comment: The code you posted looks correct, so you need to add more info. Extract the piece of your code that causes problems, including the input data. Make it into a small standalone script and post it here.

Comment: Please show the complete `foreach` block. I'd bet the contents of my fridge that the error isn't in that conditional expression.

Comment: I've added the full foreach block of code. there is an else statement.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. For the purpose of what i was doing, i rewrote the code so that it doesn't use the above code and doesn't use hashrefs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have an elsif clause?  Some warnings in elsif will be reported with the if's line number.

Answer (score 0):

comment the Data Dumper and run , sometimes data dumper will derefer/unrefer the object.